# How to run `make` on a `makefile` target and ignore prerequisites?

Tags: makefile, target, prerequisites

Let's say I have a `make` target `abc` with prerequisites `x`, `y`, and `z`.

```
abc: x y z
    echo 'Do something'
```

Is there not some simple way to run `make` and ignore the prerequisites, such that it runs `abc` without first running `x`, `y`, and `z`?

Comment: I was thinking a command line arg, like, `make abc --ignore-prerequisites`, but I don't see anything in `man make` about this. I'm kind of surprised. Seems like a very common use case. For context, we have a large pipeline with jobs that take a long time, and sometimes we just want to run the target immediately, even if something small has changed and requires an update. Or, there are cases where some of our prerequisites aren't well programmed yet, and they run even if they are up-to-date. So this would be a useful case to get around such situations temporarily.

Comment: There is no such thing.  In the context of `make` it doesn't make sense: when you say "target X has prerequisite Y", it means that Y is a requirement for X.  It wouldn't make sense to try to build X if Y wasn't built or up to date: if you did that then X's timestamp would now be higher than Y's, and when you re-ran make it would say "up to date" even though Y might have been updated, and X doesn't reflect that update.

Comment: I had a feeling that someone would respond with that: that it doesn't make sense because of how `make` is designed. I understand that for production. But the development process is different. When you have a long, complex pipeline like hours that involves long running jobs and downloads of files that are 100s of megs, and you're just doing development, (i) small changes to things don't matter, and (ii) sometimes certain prereqs run when they don't actually need to. It's a shame that `make` doesn't have this; fairly myopic design flaw.

Comment: If you want a different target without those prerequisites just write it.  If all the commands are the same use define.  Then other people looking at your setup won't have to guess about what matters because you'll have it explicitly written down, which is the entire point of make.

Comment: @JoeFlack _fairly myopic design flaw_: congratulations, you discovered a major design flaw in a 46-years old tool used by millions of developers. Seriously, try `touch x; make abc`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ make
echo x updated
x updated
echo y updated
y updated
echo z updated
z updated
echo all updated
all updated

$ make noreq=y
echo all updated
all updated
```

How it's done:

```
ifdef noreq
req :=
else
req = $(1)
endif

.PHONY: all x y z

all: $(call req,x y z)
    echo $@ updated

x y z:
    echo $@ updated
```

Note that a GNU `Makefile` can examine the value of the variable `MKCMDGOALS` and calculate other variables from that. You could have it that when certain targets are explicitly given on the command line (and thus appear in `MKCMDGOALS`) then the `noreq` flags comes into effect, and those targets adjust their behavior with the macro.

**CAVEAT:** In the `noreq` mode, the target actually does not have prerequisites, so your rule cannot refer to prerequisites via `$^` or `$<`.